# Mockk - ClassCastException when mocking final class that implements multiple interfaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, kotlin, mockk

I'm trying to use a mock of this Java class:

```
public final class HttpSecurity extends
        AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>
        implements SecurityBuilder<DefaultSecurityFilterChain>,
        HttpSecurityBuilder<HttpSecurity>
```

So I've created a mock like so:

```
private val httpSecurity: HttpSecurity = mockk(relaxed = true)
```

in order to test this bit of Java code:

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().
                headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()....etc
```

and I'm getting the following error when I try and use it

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.HttpSecurityBuilder$Subclass2 cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
```

Test class here:

```
package com.whatever

import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.mockkClass
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

import org.springframework.core.env.Environment
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity

internal class SecurityConfigTest {


    private val authManager: AuthenticationManager = mockk()
    val env : Environment = mockk()
    private val httpSecurity: HttpSecurity = mockk(relaxed = true)

    val securityConfig : SecurityConfig = SecurityConfig(authManager,env)

    @Test
    fun configure() {
        securityConfig.configure(httpSecurity)
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: It seems like `mockk` creates a type as relaxed return value of the builder methods. Try to mock every single method manually to return the `HttpSecurity` from there.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I might be able to get away without doing that, but I guess not :-)

Comment: Added an issue https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the template argument type is erased and not possible to recover.  The only solution is to specify mock directly so that `reified` type will capture actual class:

```
val mockk = mockk<HttpSecurity>(relaxed = true)
val csrf = mockk.csrf()
every { csrf.disable() } returns mockk(relaxed = true)
val disable = csrf.disable()
disable.headers()
```